# Error when trying to promote SSOTicket

Tags: single-sign-on, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I am trying to issue a SSO ticket for a FTP send port. I have created affiliate application with a mapping that is working for a receive port.

For the send port I am using a pipeline component in encode stage with just standard code:

```
ISSOTicket ssoTicket = new ISSOTicket();
        inmsg.Context.Promote("SSOTicket",
           "http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/system-properties", ssoTicket.IssueTicket(0));

return inmsg;
```

When I try to promote the result from `IssueTicket(0)` I get an error message saying that

> The property "SSOTicket" has a value with length greater than 256 characters.

How is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. The problem was that I tried to promote the SSOTicket property when I should have used inmsg.Context.Write.

Comment: Sure, Context.Promote(...) creates Property Field, Context.Write(...) creates Distinguished Filed. In documentation Property Field has limit size to 256 symbols, but Distinguished is unlimited.